# A result about Infinite series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{(1+a)!n!}{(n+1+a)!}}= \frac{1}{a}$
where $ 0<a<1$. 
I accidentally found this result by using wolframalpha, but I don't know how to prove it...

Comment: If $a=\frac12$, what do you think $(1+a)!$ is?

Comment: Hint: $\displaystyle\;\frac{(1+a)!n!}{(n+1+a)!} = (a+1)\frac{\Gamma(a+1)\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(a+n+2)} = (a+1)\int_0^1 (1-\lambda)^a \lambda^n d\lambda$

Comment: You do not need the $a \lt 1$ restriction.  Another way of writing this is $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{{n+m \choose n}} = \dfrac{1}{m-1}$ for $m>1$